# Python / pynput: How to get relative mouse position on change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mouse, pynput

I'd like to get the **relative** mouse position on change.

It's possible to **set** it absolute:
`mouse.position = (10, 20)`

or relative:
 `mouse.move(5, -5)`

But I can only **get** the current, absolute one: `mouse.position`

Source:
https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/mouse.html

Is there anything like `mouse.position_relative`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get `mouse.position`, move relative from that point with `mouse.move(10, 20)` and again retrieve `mouse.position` and calculate the difference between `x1` and `x2` and between `y1` and `y2` ?

For example, lets say mouse is at `(100, 150)` position:

```
p1 = mouse.position  # Becomes (100, 150)
mouse.move(10, 20)
p2 = mouse.position  # Becomes (110, 170)
diff = tuple(map(lambda d1, d2: d2 - d1, p1, p2)) # Becomes (10, 20)
```